# How to manually edit a macro for replacing a list of characters in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: macros, sublime-text-2

I first tried recording a macro, but instead of recording the character sequence it records my commands and movements without arguments, like this:

```
"args":
    {
        "close_panel": true
    },
    "command": "replace_all"
```

So how could I manually edit a `.sublime-macro` file to do a case sensitive replace for a list of unicode characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the RegReplace Plugin
https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=4594

I believe it works best in ST3.

From
http://geeklit.blogspot.com/2013/09/scripting-regular-expressions.html

```
// Test the RegReplace Sublime Plugin
   "test_reg_replace": {
   "find" : "testxxxxx",
   "replace": "it works!"
 }
```